# QCustomPlot in MSVS2012

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I succeeded in building a program in visual studio 2012 that runs QT without the plugin. I included the QT include folder and manually added the libraries to the resources. And it compiled and ran.

Now I wanted to use QCustomPlot in the same way, without the QtAddin plugin. I tried multiple projects, where I added QCustomPlot's .h and .cpp and tried to compile, but it gives me tons of linker problems(http://pastebin.com/SWVXktBk). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Windows 7 x64, QT 5.4.1,

Comment: I have not used Visual studio to compile qt programms, but you are not linking with moc files, that are generated for qcustomplot files.

Comment: After applying moc to qcustomplot.h, should I try to add this .h and the generated.cpp to my project? Because it still gives linker errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours, I found it.
As *UldisK* pointed, I had to moc the header.
I followed everything in here: http://ldmartin68.com/QTSetup4VSNET.html

In windows cmd

```
moc qcustomplot.h > moc_qcustomplot.cpp
```

then simply add the generated file to the project, and voila worked.
In the end you should have in the project:

- the original qcustomplot.h
- the original qcustomplot.cpp
- the generated moc_qcustomplot.cpp

Comment: Wish I could give this more upvotes. Also note that you have to use the Qt terminal.